# Using try after except is not working on Python

Tags: python, cs50, try-except

I'm doing exercise 4 on CS50P "outdated" and after trying to make the code work with if/else statements I came across a solution that used try/except for dealing with cases instead of if/else. In the following code I don't understand why the second except gets executed and thus, renders the second part of the code useless.

```
months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
]

while True:
    msg = input("Date: ")
    try:
        msg = msg.split("/")
        msg[0] = int(msg[0])
        msg[1] = int(msg[1])
        msg[2] = int(msg[2])
        if 0 < msg[0] < 13 and 0 < msg[1] < 32 and 0 < msg[2]:
            MM = f"{msg[0]:02}"
            DD = f"{msg[1]:02}"
            YY = f"{msg[2]:02}"
            break
    except:
        try:
            msg = msg.split(" ")
            msg[0] = int(months.index(msg[0])+1)
            msg[1] = msg[1].replace(",","")
            msg[1] = int(msg[1])
            msg[2] = int(msg[2])
            if 0 < msg[0] < 13 and 0 < msg[1] < 32 and 0 < msg[2]:
                MM = f"{msg[0]:02}"
                DD = f"{msg[1]:02}"
                YY = f"{msg[2]:02}"
                break
        except:

            print()
            pass

print(YY,MM,DD, sep="-")
```

When I try to execute the msg.split(" ") part first, it does work and then the following part doesn't work. Right now I have only been able to execute the first part (the code before the except). I would like to know where is the error since the terminal does not show any.

Comment: you are supressing errors with exception handelling...run part2 seperatly without any try block see what it says

Comment: if you want to now error in try catch, catch error in `except` , like `except Error as e: print(e) `

Comment: hey, can you explain what are you trying to achieve with this program? coz I see some mistakes.

Comment: The runtime behaviour of your code will depend entirely on the input string. Give an example of input and show the program's output. Looks like you're trying to allow for input in two forms - i.e., 'MM/DD/YY' and 'MM DD YY'. Then you're trying to validate the input in terms of year, month and day ranges. Take a look at the *datetime* module for some useful functionality

Comment: Swapped "msg" for "ms" after being stated the first time, code now runs properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a linear approach to this problem you should write two discrete functions for handling the two possible input date formats.

The allowed formats are:

```
MM/DD/YYYY
MM DD, YYYY
```

In the second format MM is a month full name - e.g., September

Use the datetime module to try to construct a datetime object from the user input. Anything invalid in the user input will cause an exception to be raised during construction of the datetime object.

```
from calendar import month_name
from datetime import datetime

# Possibly MM/DD/YYYY format
def type_1(s):
    if len(parts := s.split('/')) == 3:
        mm, dd, yyyy = map(int, parts)
        return datetime(yyyy, mm, dd)


# Possibly MM DD, YYYY where MM is months fullname - e.g., September
def type_2(s):
    if len(parts := s.replace(',', '').split()) == 3:
        mm = [*month_name].index(parts[0])
        dd, yyyy = map(int, parts[1:])
        return datetime(yyyy, mm, dd)


while user_date := input('Enter a date: '):
    for func in type_1, type_2:
        try:
            if d := func(user_date):
                print(datetime.strftime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
                break
        except Exception:
            pass
    else:
        print('Invalid date')
```